# Calculus involved in math-modelling

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-modeling

[image: image describing the situation]

Background: I am trying to model my arm as a spring with constant b. As the arm is on the door it compresses and it accelerates the door and decelerates me. I am trying to solve for door angle theta as a function of time, from the moment when the arm touches the door to the moment the arm is fully compressed. The compression is expressed as the difference in tangential velocity of the door at contact point and the velocity of the man. I have worked through the derivation of the formulas but came up with an error function at the end which I think is not reasonable. I may have done this wrong, so please please help if you have any thoughts. I really need your help.

the derivation is as follows:
At $t=0$, Arm just touches the door and being compressed at a rate of

$X(t)=\Delta x=(u_{man}-u_{door})t$

Where $u_{door}$ is the tangential velocity of the door at the current position $r$, which can be expressed as $r=\frac{r_0}{\cos\theta}$. From rotational kinematics, $u_{door}\cos\theta=\dot{\theta}r \Rightarrow u_{door}(t)=r_0\frac{\dot{\theta}(t)}{\cos^2{\theta(t)}}$. For the man, he experiences a deceleration due to compression of the spring, $F_{spring}=bX=ma \Rightarrow a(t)=\frac{b}{m}X(t)$. Hence, $u_{man}=u_0-\frac{b}{m}\int X(t)dt$.

This gives:

$X(t)=(u_0-r_0\frac{\dot{\theta}(t)}{\cos^2\theta(t)} -\frac{b}{m}\int X(t)dt)t$

Rearrange and substitute $g(\dot{\theta},\theta)=u_0-r_0\frac{\dot{\theta}(t)}{\cos^2\theta(t)}$:

$t^{-1}\cdot X(t)=g(\dot{\theta},\theta)  -\frac{b}{m} \int X(t)dt$

$\frac{d}{dt}(t^{-1}\cdot X(t))=\frac{d}{dt} (g(\dot{\theta},\theta)  -\frac{b}{m} \int X(t)dt)$

$-t^{-2} X(t)+t^{-1} X'(t)=\frac{d}{dt} (g(\dot{\theta},\theta))-\frac{b}{m} X(t)$

Rearrange:

$\frac{1}{t} X'(t)+(\frac{b}{m}-\frac{1}{t^2})X(t)=t\frac{d}{dt} (g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

$X'(t)+(\frac{bt}{m}-\frac{1}{t})X(t)=t\frac{d}{dt}(g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

Denote function $f$, such that $f'(t)=(\frac{bt}{m}-\frac{1}{t})$

$X'(t)+f'(t)X(t)=t\frac{d}{dt}(g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

Multiply both sides by $e^{f(t)}$:

$e^{f(t)}\cdot X'(t)+e^{f(t)}\cdot f'(t)\cdot X(t)=e^{f(t)}\cdot t\cdot \frac{d}{dt} (g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

LHS can be rewritten as

$e^{f(t)} X'(t)+e^{f(t)} f'(t)X(t)=\frac{d}{dt} (e^{f(t)} X(t))$

Hence,

$\frac{d}{dt} (e^{f(t)} X(t))=t e^{f(t)}\frac{d}{dt} (g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

$e^{f(t)} X(t)=\int t e^{f(t)} dt\cdot (g(\dot{\theta},\theta))$

from here if you substitute them in, you will find an integral of (exp(2t^2/bm))dt which is non solvable.

Comment: It sounds like $X=\Delta x$ is a displacement. I don't understand how this can be related as $\Delta x=u_{man}-u_{door}\,t$ where the $u\,$s are two non constant velocities. Having them not specified you want to solve for the door angle. Sounds totally non physical. Somewhere a conservation law should come into play.

Comment: A sketch would help here a lot.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou , hello! I have just added an image describing the situation. I hope it is clear. thanks

Comment: @KurtG. hello! I have just added an image describing the situation. I hope it is clear. thanks!

Comment: Are the following assumptions correct? a) Small angle approximations do not apply here. b) The door is perfectly rigid. In real life the flexibility of the door is higher than that of a human arm in compression and the vibrations induced (and heard) come from the door and not the arm.

Comment: You start of incorrectly with $X(t)=\Delta x=(u_{man}-u_{door})t$ Start with the equations of motion for this 2-DOF system. You need equations for $\ddot{\theta}$ and $\ddot{x}$ if you want to try to solve this problem.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt} (e^{f(t)} X(t)) = t e^{f(t)} \frac{d}{dt} g(\theta, \dot{\theta}) \implies e^{f(t)} X(t) = \int \left[ t e^{f(t)} \frac{d}{dt} g(\theta, \dot{\theta}) \right] dt$$ which is not the same as what you wrote $$\int \left[ t e^{f(t)} \right] dt \cdot g(\theta, \dot{\theta})$$

Comment: @JohnAlexiou many thanks for the comments! If I modelled the situation incorrectly, do you have any thoughts on how am I gonna find the angle of door as a function of time before the spring is fully compressed?

Comment: @MatthewCassell thanks for pointing out my mistakes! but this gets even more complicated:(

Comment: It kind of depends on the motion of the mass. Is it prescribed (man attached to the ground and pushing) or is it free (astronaut floating in space). If you assume their motion is that of constant velocity, then it is a 1-DOF problem.  A clarification also, is the door on a free hinge, or is there a rotational spring of $k$ stiffness and $c$ damping which is used in $$I \ddot{\theta} = \tau -k \theta - c \dot{\theta}$$

Comment: @MingyangPan - PS nobody said dynamics are easy.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Here I just assumed the man as a ball with mass m and travelling initially with u_0.  yes there should be a k*theta term and a c*theta_dot term. as that is generally how modern doors are designed. couldn't get my head around the problem haha!

Comment: @JohnAlexiou my approach is included in the figure, I am not sure where does the assumptions went wrong :(

Comment: @MatthewCassell if this is the case, it will make the equation even harder ( at least for me) could u provide any thoughts on how to solve this? I think applying small angle approximation would help?

Comment: @MingyangPan - cool drawings BTW. I did have a question about the orientation of the spring. As the door swings the end point follows an arc and therefore the orientation of the spring isn't vertical (and hence the force applied). But in real life sometimes you let your  hand slide on the door as it opens in order to keep the contact point in front of  you. What do you envision happens with _your_ idealization of this situation?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I tried my best to give a clear drawing haha. Your statement on real life is just what I am assuming: 'you let your hand slide on the door as it opens in order to keep the contact point in front of you.' Therefore, in my model I have the spring going in a vertical straight line as the door rotates. In this way, the tangential velocity of door at that contact point can be calculated with rotational kinematics and hence equation of (u_man-u_door)t=delta_x(compression of spring) can be obtained.  Really appreciate your communication John :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the moment arm of the spring on the pivot changes with the door angle makes this a non-solvable problem analytically and in need of a simulation.

But if you ignore this non-linearity and assume that the arm is always a distance $b$ from the pivot at all times as the hand slides along the door, then there is a solution.

Here is the notation for distances and angles that I am using, as well as a free-body diagram with all quantities shown in their positive state. Note that $x$ starts at a fixed value $x_0$ and grows smaller as the person approaches the door with speed $v_0$. I assume this speed is maintained and $\dot{x} = -v_0$

[image: fig1]

I have included a push force $F_b$ needed to maintain this constant speed as the door opens. The system has two DOF, $x$ and $\theta$, although since $x$ has prescribed motion, the system is really a 1-DOF system in terms of $\theta(t)$.

The spring force is evaluated at any instant with

$$ F_s = -k_x ( b \theta + x-x_0) -d_x ( b \dot{\theta} + \dot{x} ) \tag{1} $$

where $k_x$ and $d_x$ is the stiffness and damping coefficients for the linear spring.

The convention above is that the spring extends when both $x$ and $\theta$ grow in value. But because $x(t)$ is prescribed, you have

$$ x(t) = x_0 - v_0 t \tag{2} $$
$$ \dot{x} = -v_0 \tag{3}$$

The equation of motion of the door is very similar to what you wrote in the question

$$ I_d \ddot{\theta} = -k_\theta \,\theta -d_\theta \, \dot{\theta} + b\,F_s \tag{4} $$

Where $I_d = \tfrac{1}{3} m_d \ell^3$ is the MMOI about the pivot, and $k_\theta$ and $d_\theta$ are the rotational stiffness and damping coefficient of the door hinge.

Combine (2) and (4) to get the equation of motion of the door

$$ \ddot{\theta} + \left(\frac{b^2 k_x + k_\theta}{I_d}\right) \theta + \left( 
 \frac{b^2 d_x + d_\theta}{I_d} \right) \dot{\theta} - \left( \frac{b v_0 (d_x + k_x t)}{I_d} \right) = 0 \tag{5} $$

Now define the following parameters $\omega_n$ and $\zeta$ that would simplify the solution of the above by using the following substitution.

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \omega_n^2 & = \frac{b^2 k_x + k_\theta}{I_d} \\ 
 2 \zeta \omega_n & = \frac{b^2 d+x + d_\theta}{I_d} \\
\end{aligned} $$

Not the equation of motion (5) is re-written as

$$ \ddot{\theta} + 2 \zeta \omega_n \dot{\theta} + \omega_n^2 \theta - \frac{b _0 ( d_x + k_x t)}{I_d} = 0  \tag{5} $$

This ODE has as the solution of the following form

$$  \theta=e^{-\omega_{n}\zeta t}\left(\left(\frac{bv_{0}(2k_{x}\zeta-d_{x}\omega_{n})}{I_{d}\omega_{n}^{3}}\right)\cos(\omega t)-\left(\frac{bv_{0}(d_{x}\omega_{n}\zeta+k_{x}(1-2\zeta^{2}))}{I_{d}\omega_{n}^{3}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}\right)\sin(\omega t)\right) + \\ + \frac{bv_{0}(d_{x}\omega_{n}-2k_{x}\zeta)}{I_{d}\omega_{n}^{3}}+\frac{bk_{x}v_{0}}{I_{d}\omega_{n}^{2}}t \tag{6} $$

with $\omega = \omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$

The full solution above is subject to the following initial conditions

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\theta & =0\\
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\dot{\theta} & =0
\end{aligned} \tag{7}$$

You can verify the I.C. as well as that (6) satisfies (5) fully.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out!!! I will have a close look into the equations. BTW how do you draw those figures they look nice

Comment: I used PowerPoint. I have `IguanaTex` addon to render math, and I have my own addon I wrote to draw curves such as a spiral or a sine wave.

Comment: really appreciate your fantastic work John. you even verified by putting (6) into (5) so much hard work. thank you.